# Unity 5 and IL2CPP: cannot build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play

Been bashing my head for the past few days trying to port my droid app to iOS.

Most of the code is in-house, just using UnityAds, SIS (Simple IAP System) and GooglePlayGames plugins.

With IL2CCP on, it won't even build on Unity 5 (latest version). I get the following errors:

```
IL2CPP error for type 'GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PInvokeUtilities/OutStringMethod' in assembly '/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll'
Additional information: Build a development build for more information. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Failed running /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/il2cpp.exe --copy-level=None --enable-generic-sharing --enable-unity-event-support --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --enable-symbol-loading
"/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"
"/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll"
"/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll"
"/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll" "/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/OpenIAB_W8Plugin.dll" "/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Cloud.Analytics.dll"
"/Temp/il2cppOutput/il2cppOutput"

stdout:
IL2CPP error for type 'GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PInvokeUtilities/OutStringMethod' in assembly '/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll'
Additional information: Build a development build for more information. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
stderr:

Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.TypeDefinitionVisitor.HandleDelegate (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.TypeDefinitionVisitor.Visit (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Context context) [0x00000] in :0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Visitor.VisitTypeDefinition [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Extensions.DoAcceptTypeDefinition [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Extensions.Accept (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Visitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.IncludeCollector.ForTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.IncludeCollector.ForTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeWriter.WriteTypeDefinitionIncludes (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, Unity.IL2CPP.CppCodeWriter writer) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteTypeDefinitionFor (System.String outputDirectory, Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.Write (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition, Unity.IL2CPP.GenericsCollection.InflatedCollection allGenerics, System.String outputDir, Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition[] typeList, Unity.IL2CPP.StringLiterals.StringLiteralCollection stringLiteralCollection) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Convert (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition, Unity.IL2CPP.StringLiterals.StringLiteralCollection stringLiteralCollection, Unity.IL2CPP.GenericsCollection.InflatedCollection allGenerics) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply () [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies (System.String[] assemblies, System.String outputDir) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.TypeDefinitionVisitor.HandleDelegate (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.TypeDefinitionVisitor.Visit (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Context context) [0x00000] in :0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Visitor.VisitTypeDefinition [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Extensions.DoAcceptTypeDefinition [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Extensions.Accept (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Unity.Cecil.Visitor.Visitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.IncludeCollector.ForTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeCollection.NonTemplated.IncludeCollector.ForTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.IncludeWriter.WriteTypeDefinitionIncludes (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, Unity.IL2CPP.CppCodeWriter writer) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.WriteTypeDefinitionFor (System.String outputDirectory, Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.SourceWriter.Write (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition, Unity.IL2CPP.GenericsCollection.InflatedCollection allGenerics, System.String outputDir, Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition[] typeList, Unity.IL2CPP.StringLiterals.StringLiteralCollection stringLiteralCollection) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Convert (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition, Unity.IL2CPP.StringLiterals.StringLiteralCollection stringLiteralCollection, Unity.IL2CPP.GenericsCollection.InflatedCollection allGenerics) [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply () [0x00000] in :0
at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies (System.String[] assemblies, System.String outputDir) [0x00000] in :0

    UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
    UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:66)
    UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(ICollection1, String, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:404) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:275) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Exception: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:68)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection1 userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:404) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:275) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor pp, BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String stagingAreaDataManaged, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Error building Player: Exception: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
```

Comment: Check this this issue is solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155613/10749547

Answer (score 2):

See here:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-exe-error.311499/

and here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/433

Others are having the issue, specifically with the Google game play services plugin.  I don't see a solution yet, but a Unity employee on the Unity link said he would look into it.

Update: The latest Unity patch 5.0.0p2 fixed this error for me:
http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases